# Prevent buttons with same class from being clicked simultaneously

Tags: javascript, button, foreach, event-handling

I have two buttons that have the same class name and have same functionality but different inputs must be added, so I used `document.querySelectorAll()` and the `forEach()` method to get them, but now when I click one, the other gets clicked too. Is there a way I can prevent this without having two `addEventListener` for both buttons? Enable it to click only one button at a time.

My code:

```
let inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('.inputElement');
const submitBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.submitBtn');
const backersElement = document.querySelector('.number-of-backers');

let donationsMade = [];

function calculateBamboo() {

    inputElements.forEach(inputElement => {
        const inputValue = parseFloat(inputElement.value);

        if (inputValue < 25 || inputValue === '') return alert('Pledge must be at least $25.');
        
        donationsMade.push(inputValue);
        const donationsTotal = donationsMade.reduce((a, b) => a += b);
        pledgedAmount.textContent = `$${donationsTotal}`;
        backersElement.textContent = donationsMade.length;

        return donationsTotal;

    })
}
submitBtn.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', calculateBamboo);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually "clicking" both buttons. What's happening is the following:

Your `calculateBamboo()` functions loops through all the inputElements: `inputElements.forEach()`; and you're executing your logic for all the inputs. So, no matter which button you press, `calculateBamboo()` is processing **each** input.

Passing target input using data-attributes will help you to identify which input *belongs* to clicked button

Also, @JerryBen is right, you don't need to add event listener to each button but instead, we can *wrap* all the buttons in one element, add event listener to it and identify which element was clicked.

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const pledgedAmount = document.querySelector('.backed-users');
const backersElement = document.querySelector('.number-of-backers');

wrapper.addEventListener('click', calculateBamboo);

let donationsMade = [];

function calculateBamboo(event) {
  /* Here you can access to the event argument,
    which contains target: the clicked element*/
  const el = event.target;

  if (el.nodeName !== 'BUTTON' || !el.classList.contains('submitBtn')) {
    return;
  }

  // Get target input from button's data-attr
  const targetInput = el.dataset.input;
  const inputElement = document.querySelector(`input[data-input="${targetInput}"]`);

  // Continue with the code you had...
  const inputValue = parseFloat(inputElement.value) || 0;

  if (inputValue < 25 || inputValue === '') return alert('Pledge must be at least $25.');

  donationsMade.push(inputValue);
  const donationsTotal = donationsMade.reduce((a, b) => a += b);
  pledgedAmount.textContent = `$${donationsTotal}`;
  backersElement.textContent = donationsMade.length;

  return donationsTotal;
}
```

```html
<div class="backed">
  <h1 class="backed-users">0</h1>
</div>

<div class="backers">
  <h1 class="number-of-backers">0</h1>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class=".pledge-edition">
    <div class="pledge">
      <section class="pledgeTwo"></section>
      <div>
        <h2>Bamboo Stand</h2>
        <a href="#">Pledge $25 or more</a>
        <div>
          <h2>101</h2>
          <div>left</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>
      You get an ergonomic stand made of natural bamboo. You've helped us launch our promotional campaign, and you’ll be added to a special Backer member list.
    </p>

    <div class="pledge-amount">
      <p>Enter your pledge</p>
      <div>
        <input class="inputElement bambooInputElement" data-input="1" placeholder="$25" min="25" type="number">
        <button class="submitBtn bambooBtn" data-input="1">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=".pledge-edition">
    <div class="pledge">
      <section class="pledgeThree"></section>
      <div>
        <h2>Black Edition Stand</h2>
        <a href="#">Pledge $75 or more</a>
        <div>
          <h2>64</h2>
          <div>left</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>
      You get a Black Special Edition computer stand and a personal thank you. You’ll be added to our Backer member list. Shipping is included.
    </p>

    <div class="pledge-amount">
      <p>Enter your pledge</p>
      <div>
        <input class="inputElement bambooInputElement" data-input="2" placeholder="$75" min="75" type="number">
        <button class="submitBtn blackEditionBtn" data-input="2" placeholder="$75" min="75">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it worked I took the second option "Passing target input using data-attributes" but these elements are not showing the values that were entered ````backersElement.textContent = donationsMade.length;
pledgedAmount.textContent = `$${donationsTotal};````

Comment: this one works ````backersElement.textContent = donationsMade.length;```` but the other one returns null

Comment: I think this should work. I made a small tweak to add a good practice mentioned below, and made the example more... explicit, because I noticed you were missing a line (and that was the reason for the bug you mentioned below as well). Tell me here if anything else goes wrong or if you don't understand something, so I can keep track of your comments and update the answer. ;)

Comment: Still not working and I think with this approach is because my buttons are not exactly on the same container, please check my answer below I've updated my HTML

Comment: I had a couple of typos, but the logic was correct. Corrected it and tested using your updated HTML: it works. Copy/pasting this code should work for you, but I'd recommend to analyze it anyways so you understand what's happening. There you have a snippet to see it working.

Comment: Just finished analyzing and retyping it on my editor so I can understand it better, it works. Thanks a lot for your patience man.

Answer (score 0):

Adding event listeners to each button is considered a bad practice. Instead, use a single event listener to rule them all:

1. Wrap the buttons in a div element
2. Add click event only to the div wrapper
3. Pass an `event` object as an argument to the handler function
4. The event handler function will use the `event.target` to identify which specific button was clicked:

`function calculateBamboo(evt){ const inputValue = parseFloat(evt.target.value) }`

I hope this helps

Comment: I considered this I wasn't sure it will work the buttons are on different sections of the page. Would it work if I wrap them on divs with the same class name

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet with HTML + JS please?

Comment: Please check on my answer I posted the snippets

Comment: Your code contains only one button element. Am I missing something there?

Comment: Sorry about I thought I copied the whole code, I've just edited it

Answer (score 0):

My current JS

```
function calculateBamboo(target) {

    let inputElement = document.querySelector(`input[data-input="${target}"]`);
        donationsMade.push(inputElement);
        const donationsTotal = donationsMade.reduce((a, b) => a += b);
        backersElement.textContent = donationsMade.length;
        pledgedAmount.textContent = `$${donationsTotal}`;
        successElement.style.display = 'block';
        return donationsTotal;
}
submitBtn.forEach(button => {
    const target = button.dataset.input;
    button.addEventListener('click', calculateBamboo.bind(target));
})
```

HTML buttons and input

```
<!-- this is how my buttons are placed -->
<div id="wrapper">
<div class=".pledge-edition">
        <div class="pledge">
          <section class="pledgeTwo"></section>
          <div>
            <h2>Bamboo Stand</h2>
            <a href="#">Pledge $25 or more</a>
            <div>
              <h2>101</h2>
              <div>left</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <p>
          You get an ergonomic stand made of natural bamboo. You've helped us launch our promotional campaign, and
          you’ll be added to a special Backer member list.
        </p>

        <div class="pledge-amount">
          <p>Enter your pledge</p>
          <div>
            <input class="inputElement bambooInputElement" data-input="1" placeholder="$25" min="25" type="number">
            <button class="submitBtn bambooBtn" data-input="1">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class=".pledge-edition">
        <div class="pledge">
          <section class="pledgeThree"></section>
          <div>
            <h2>Black Edition Stand</h2>
            <a href="#">Pledge $75 or more</a>
            <div>
              <h2>64</h2>
              <div>left</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <p>
          You get a Black Special Edition computer stand and a personal thank you. You’ll be added to our Backer
          member list. Shipping is included.
        </p>

        <div class="pledge-amount">
          <p>Enter your pledge</p>
          <div>
            <input class="inputElement bambooInputElement" data-input="2" placeholder="$75" min="75" type="number">
            <button class="submitBtn blackEditionBtn" data-input="2" placeholder="$75" min="75">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

HTML for when the values are entered

```
<div class="backed">
   <h1 class="backed-users">0</h1>
</div>

<div class="backers">
  <h1 class="number-of-backers">0</h1>
</div>
```